# SyndicationFeed class in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am trying to use the SyndicationFeed class in Xamarin to pull RSS feed data in to an iOS application.

I am using system.ServiceModel - but I cannot find this class. Is SyndicationFeed supported in Xamarin? And if so - where would I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.ServiceModel.Syndication is not shipped with Xamarin.  You can find a lists of shipped assemblies [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/assemblies/).

Comment: That's a useful reference page... Thanks, Guy.